# How can I switch development mode to production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What I have done is,

1. I changed /etc/httpd/conf/httpd/conf like this

   `RailsEnv development` => `RailsEnv production`
2. cmd $ bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV="production"
3. cmd $ bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"
4. I restarted server, and tried to access but it gets this error.

> We're sorry but something went wrong

config/environments/production.rb

```
Sample::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
   config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
  
  
end
```

Comment: What's your web server for production? apache2 + passenger?

Comment: @HUSTEN - @apneadiving is saying you do not need to wrap `production` in quotes.

Comment: What about running `rails console production` ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Apache2 and passenger

Comment: So yeah, you've done what's necessary I think ... restart apache2 and you're done (granted your app is well configured to talk to production db etc)

Comment: @Kyle I tried not to wrap and did again but the same result:(

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto I see it created production database and migrated all the tables what I need. It seems something else more than migration:(

Comment: @MrYoshiji rails c production works.  why

Comment: Btw, you can change the environment directly in the Virtual Host I think, allowing a more specific and per-app environment. What is written in the log files ?

Comment: @Sparda Could you please show me regular way?

Comment: You can just write this in your Virtual Host : `RailsEnv production`... And is there anything worth of interest in your log files ?

Comment: Everyone, Do I need $ bundle install when I'm switching to production?

Comment: This doesn't seem critical so if you don't know, just try it and let us know the results. : )

Comment: @Sparda I tried bundle install but the same result:( I'm so stucked....

Comment: what does your log say? maybe you didn't set up your database correctly.

Comment: @Jean-Paul In production.log It just has migration logs. That's it! really weird:( I did access to the page. It should show something in there just like development.log

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (logo.png isn't precompiled):

Comment: I did rails s -e production then I accessed to app. That's what it said on my terminal

Comment: `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` should fix it ... remember to execute it when you change your assets

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto Thanks I did that but it's still the same:( Is there something wrong with config/environment/production.rb?

Comment: If I tried rails s -e production, again. It says Error compiling CSS asset:(

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto I added config/environment/production.rb to the bottom of my question. Could please check this?

Answer (score 0):

Its another way round 
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
Prefix RAILS_ENV=production if you want anything to run in the production mode.

Comment: what do you mean? How can I do that?